# How to display the uwp application in the tray at the bottom right corner of the system

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

Can uwp applications be displayed in the tray on the lower right corner of the system desktop?

Comment: In addition, did uwp not minimize and close the event?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not supported directly for UWP apps to put themselves into the systray, but you can add a desktop extension to your package that can live in the systray and act as a proxy for your UWP. Here is a blog post on that:

https://stefanwick.com/2017/06/24/uwp-app-with-systray-extension/

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. This article is very useful to me. I will try to reply to you later.

Comment: Although this example does not completely solve my problem, but it provides me with reference and train of thought, thank you!

Comment: Then how does Spotify do it?

Comment: Spotify is not a UWP application @Barry

Comment: Interesting, it's published on the store, is stored in the C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ folder, and contains a AppXManifest.xml. Not sure how they pulled that one off

Comment: @Barry Publishing non-UWP apps to the Store is supported since 2016: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bridges/desktop/

Comment: Interesting. I know what I must do then. Thank you!!

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT Is there official msdn article on that matter ?

Comment: @IronHide No, I am afraid there is not. This is not a documented feature. It rather is a workaround I have posted on my personal blog.